# How to add automatic toggle into video

Tags: wordpress, video, jwplayer, self-hosting

I have `JWPlayer` for `Wordpress` from ilghera. I use it for my website and i'm publishing video content in my site. This plugin that i use from ilghera gives me the option to add different qualities for a video but they only work manually.

I want my users to open the video just like a youtube video and video itself changes the quality due to users internet connection speed.

Can anyone help me? And whats the price for such a software etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've converted my mp4 file to m3u8. Created a playlist same as https://docs.peer5.com/guides/production-ready-hls-vod/ in this link shows. But when i try to play it on http://stream-tester.jwplayer.com it gave me 232011 error code.

---

Update**

I've solved the problem. Ffmpeg was working fine but only problem was jwplayer and hlsplayer.net were given me the same error which is cross domain access denied. So opened the apache and gave this command :

> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

It worked!

Answer (score 1):

The behavior/technology you described is adaptive bitrate (ABR), which uses real-time bandwidth data to switch between higher and lower resolutions of a video.

In order to take advantage of ABR, you must use a video format that supports it, such as HLS (files with .m3u8 extension) or MPEG-Dash (.mpd). You can see an example stream [here](https://www.jwplayer.com/developers/stream-tester/).

If one of these streams is configured, JW Player will handle ABR and resolution switching automatically. If you are using JW Player's platform technology (i.e. Dashboard), and upload a video, HLS conversions are provided for you.

Comment: I want to use it on my own server, can i use ffmpeg to turn my videos into m3u8 extension and after that use it on jwplayer by adding the url ?